# Is there a notation for repeated nCr?

Tags: combinatorics, notation

I have a use for a repeating n choose r function. I have not been able to find any information about whether this exists already. If it does, what is the correct notation I should use?

((nCr)Cr)Cr...  for a total of m 'choose' operations

so 4 choose 2, 5 times =

```
((((4 choose 2) choose 2)choose 2) choose 2) choose 2=
6 C2 C2 C2 C2 = 
15 C2 C2 C2 = 
105 C2 C2 =
5460 C2 = 
14903070
```

The rapid growth of the value is deliberate.

Comment: What are you using this thing for?  It looks delightfully mad.

Comment: Otherwise, you can just introduce some notation such as $n\, C^m(r)$.

Comment: I will be generating test data for HPC applications. The simplest way to get an insane number of computations that I have thought of so far is: "groups all results from previous iteration, run 'the function' on those groups, and generate the next iteration for grouping"

Comment: The 'choose 2' is a specific case where the function being tested requires 2 parameters. choosing groups of size=r is still useful for different algorithms.